# Back to previous page after deletion of row

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include_once "library/inc.sesadmin.php";
include_once "library/inc.library.php";
include_once "mhsfunc.php";

$filterSQL  = "";


if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {
  $txtNim     = trim($_POST['txtNim']);
  $txtNama    = trim($_POST['txtNama']);
  $cmbProdi   = trim($_POST['cmbProdi']);
  $txtSmt     = trim($_POST['txtSmt']);
  $cmbSmt     = trim($_POST['cmbSmt']);

if($cmbSmt<>""){
$filterSQL = "WHERE khs.nim='$txtNim' AND khs.smt='$cmbSmt'";  
}else {
$filterSQL = "WHERE khs.nim='$txtNim'";  
}
} else {
$filterSQL = "WHERE khs.nim='zzz'";  
}

#tampilkan hasil isian di form
$dataNim      =isset($_POST['txtNim']) ? $_POST['txtNim'] : '';
$dataNama     =isset($_POST['txtNama']) ? $_POST['txtNama'] : '';
$dataProdi    =isset($_POST['cmbProdi']) ? $_POST['cmbProdi'] : '';
$dataSmtMhs   =isset($_POST['txtSmt']) ? $_POST['txtSmt'] : '';
$dataSmtKrs   =isset($_POST['cmbSmt']) ? $_POST['cmbSmt'] : '';


# FOR PAGING (PEMBAGIAN HALAMAN)
$baris      = 50;
$hal          = isset($_GET['hal']) ? $_GET['hal'] : 1;
$pageSql    = "SELECT * FROM khs $filterSQL";
$pageQry    = mysql_query($pageSql, $koneksidb) or die ("error paging:    ".mysql_error());
$jumlah     = mysql_num_rows($pageQry);
$maks         = ceil($jumlah/$baris);
$mulai      = $baris * ($hal-1); 
$jmlsks     = 0;
$jmlbobot   = 0;
$ipk        = 0;
?>
<table width="800" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="table-border">
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" align="right"><h1><b>DATA KRS MAHASISWA </b></h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="form1" target="_self">
   <table class="table-list" width="1000" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" >

    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="font-size:20px; font-family:Cambria" bgcolor="#F5F5F5"><b>FILTER DATA</b></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="169"><b>NIM Mahasiswa</b></td>
      <td width="5"><b>:</b></td>
      <td width="260"><input name="txtNim" type="text" id="txtNim" value="<?php echo $dataNim; ?>" size="15" maxlength="12" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><b>Nama Mahasiswa</b></td>
      <td><b>:</b></td>
      <td><input name="txtNama" type="text" id="txtNama" value="<?php echo $dataNama; ?>" size="40" maxlength="40" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><b>Program Studi</b></td>
      <td><b>:</b></td>
      <td><select name="cmbProdi" id="cmbProdi">
          <option value="KOSONG">....</option>
          <?php
            $dataSql = "SELECT * FROM prodi ORDER BY kode";
            $dataQry = mysql_query($dataSql, $koneksidb) or die ("Gagal Query".mysql_error());
            while ($dataRow = mysql_fetch_array($dataQry)) {
              if ($dataRow['kode'] == $cmbProdi) {
              $cek = " selected";
            } else { $cek=""; }
              echo "<option value='$dataRow[kode]' $cek> [$dataRow[kode]] $dataRow[nama]</option>";
            }
          ?>
           </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><b>Semester Mahasiswa</b></td>
      <td><b>:</b></td>
      <td><input name="txtSmt" type="text" id="txtSmt" value="<?php echo $dataSmtMhs; ?>" size="3" maxlength="1" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><b>Semester KRS</b></td>
      <td><b>:</b></td>
      <td><select name="cmbSmt" id="cmbSmt">
          <option value="">ALL</option>
          <?php
           $pilihan = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5","6");
           foreach ($pilihan as $semester) {
              if ($dataSmtKrs==$semester) {
                    $cek="selected";
              } else { $cek = "";}
                echo "<option value='$semester' $cek>$semester</option>";
              }
          ?>
          </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value=" Submit" id="btnSubmit" /></td>
    </tr>

   </table>
</form>

<tr>
  <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
  <table class="table-list" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">

  <tr>
    <td colspan="5"><a href="?open=KRS-Add" target="_self"><img src="images/btn_add_data.png" height="30" border="0" /></a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width="28" align="center" bgcolor="#F5F5F5"><b>No</b></td>
    <td width="63" bgcolor="#F5F5F5"><b>NIM</b></td>
    <td width="53" bgcolor="#F5F5F5"><b>KDMK</b></td>
    <td width="368" bgcolor="#F5F5F5"><b>NAMA MK</b></td>
    <td width="35" bgcolor="#F5F5F5"><b>SMT</b></td>
    <td width="30" bgcolor="#F5F5F5"><b>SKS</b></td>
    <td width="26" bgcolor="#F5F5F5"><b>TM</b></td>
    <td width="21" bgcolor="#F5F5F5"><b>PR</b></td>
    <td width="19" bgcolor="#F5F5F5"><b>LP</b></td>
    <td width="252" bgcolor="#F5F5F5"><b>DOSEN (NIDN/NAMA)</b></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b>Tools</b></td>
</tr>
      <?php
        $mySql = "SELECT      khs.id_khs, khs.nim, khs.kdmk, khs.nmmk,  khs.smt, mtkul.sks, mtkul.tm, mtkul.pr, mtkul.lp,mtkul.nodos
                  FROM        khs
                  INNER JOIN  mtkul
                  ON          khs.tahun=mtkul.tahun AND khs.prodi=mtkul.prodi AND khs.smt=mtkul.smt AND khs.kdmk=mtkul.kode $filterSQL 
                  ORDER BY    khs.smt, khs.kdmk LIMIT $mulai, $baris";
        $myQry = mysql_query($mySql, $koneksidb)  or die ("Query salah : ".mysql_error());
        $nomor  = $mulai; 
        while ($myData = mysql_fetch_array($myQry)) {
          $nomor++;
          $nidn     = $myData['nodos'];
          $Kode     = $myData['id_khs'];
          $jmlsks   = $jmlsks+$myData['sks'];
          $qryDosen = "SELECT * from dosen WHERE nidn=$nidn";
          $qryCek   = mysql_query($qryDosen, $koneksidb) or die ("Eror Query".mysql_error()); 
          $myData2  = mysql_fetch_assoc($qryCek);
          if(mysql_num_rows($qryCek)>=1){
              $namaDosen=$myData2['nama'];
          } else {$namaDosen=$nidn;}
          // Gradasi warna baris
          if($nomor%2==1) { $warna="#FFFFFF"; } else {$warna="#F5F5F5";}
        ?>
  <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $warna; ?>">
    <td align="center"><?php echo $nomor; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $myData['nim']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $myData['kdmk']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $myData['nmmk']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $myData['smt']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $myData['sks']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $myData['tm']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $myData['pr']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $myData['lp']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $namaDosen ?></td>
    <td width="56" align="center"><a href="?open=KRS-Delete&Kode=<?php echo  $Kode; ?>" target="_self" alt="Delete Data" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure ...?')">Delete</a></td>

//here is the KRS-Delete.php
<?php
include_once "library/inc.sesadmin.php";

 // Get From URL
 if(empty($_GET['Kode'])){
   echo "<b>Data yang dihapus tidak ada</b>";
 }
 else {
    $Kode   = $_GET['Kode'];
$mySql = "DELETE FROM khs WHERE id_khs='$Kode'";
$myQry = mysql_query($mySql, $koneksidb) or die ("Eror hapus data".mysql_error());

if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
    header('location: ' .$_GET['Kode']); 
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
         "alert('Data Berhasil Di Hapus');".
         "</script>";

    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=?open=KRS-Data'>";

} else {
    echo "Data tidak ditemukan !! <br><br>";
}
```

My Problem is that when I successfully delete a row, I want my page to go back showing the previous table shown, minus the row that I have already deleted with the exact same page number. What I need to parse into and out of KRS-Delete.php

Answer (score 0):

When building UI pages that involve multiple steps, I prefer to put all steps in the same PHP file.  I start with `$foo = @$_GET['foo']; if ($foo) DoFoo();` to see if this call needs to do the "foo" step (such as doing the DELETE).  After DoFoo(), I usually fall into the main code, which presents the UI page identical to (or similar to) the original page.

In addition to avoiding navigation problem you mentioned, it allows me to have 'all' the stuff for this UI in one file.  Often there is a lot of common code, too.

Comment: it is mean i need to cal javascript function inside my html right ?, actually i am new to this prog language. I would appreciate if you could give me more guidance. Thanks.

Comment: In my example, DoFoo() is in PHP.  Javascript needs to be in <script> tags and is usually invoked from something like <button...OnClick=js_routine()> when the user clicks the button.  Try to avoid Javascript, a newbie has enough to deal with with Html, PHP, and MySQL.